# Different first page header footer macro excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below macro to format my excel file headers. I need my first page header to be different from the second page. I want to add "Continued"after the first page in the header. Could you please help. Thank in Advance.

```
shDD.Select
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftHeader = "&""Arial,Bold""&12" & Range("EIIname").Value & Chr(10) & "&5" _
    & Chr(10) & "&10" _
    & Range("HdrDDn").Value & Chr(10) _
    & "&""Arial,bold""&10" & Range("HdrPeriod").Value & Chr(10)
End With
```

Comment: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28213936/Macro-to-Fill-Different-First-Page-Header-or-Footer-in-Excel-2010-Worksheet.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to define that the first header is different. And then you can fill the `.FirstPage` headers with contents.

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = "Continued …"
End With
```