Different first page header footer macro excel - a more involved example
This is a followup to the 7+ year old post at Different first page header footer macro excel .
I've basically cut and pasted code from https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-put-a-value-from-a-cell-into-a-footer-or/972b5bca-f6ea-4935-84a1-7d542a4a2ba2 , modified it, and it works (see below). But I cannot figure out where to put the different first page header code.
I've tried adding .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True right after With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index).PageSetup but that didn't work. I also tried putting
With Worksheets(1).PageSetup
   .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
End With

in the same place (see below), and that didn't work eether. Sorry, guys, I just haven't been allowed to do fun stuff like this for the last 20 years and I'm klewless.
Can someone teach me how to fish here? Here's the code (by the way, the notes at the end from Kevin are from the original programmer, not me):
' Insert value of specific cell in active sheet's header
' Code from https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-can-i-put-a-value-from-a-cell-into-a-footer-or/972b5bca-f6ea-4935-84a1-7d542a4a2ba2
'
' Excel does not support cell references in headers and footers but the functionality can be simulated with VBA.
' The VBA code required to simulate cell references in headers and footers is listed at the end of this article.
' Once this code is in place, a cell reference can be added to a header or footer by inserting this syntax into the header or footer text:
'
'   ^[Cell:A1]
'   ^[Cell:Sheet1!A1]
'   ^[Cell:NamedRange]
'
' If no sheet name is included in the cell reference then the cell is assumed to be on the same sheet for which the header or footer is defined.
' The cell references will be substituted with the cell values whenever the worksheet is printed from the Excel application.
'
' To resolve the cell references when printing from VBA use the following example code:
'
'   ThisWorkbook.SaveAndSetHeaders
'   Sheets(1).PrintOut
'   ThisWorkbook.RestoreHeaders
'
'Below is the code to simulate cell references in headers and footers. Add this code to the ThisWorkbook module. A description of how this code works and why it was written this way follows below.

Private HeaderSave() As Variant
Private HeaderChanged() As Variant

Public Sub ChangeHeaderName_andPrint()

   Dim Index As Long

   ' Save and set header and footer text
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   ReDim HeaderSave(1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
   ReDim HeaderChanged(1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count, 0 To 5)
   For Index = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
      With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index).PageSetup
'''''''' Next three lines added by Steve VanSlyck on 2024-09-25 based on guidance from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42896952/different-first-page-header-footer-macro-excel
         With Worksheets(1).PageSetup
            .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
         End With
         HeaderSave(Index) = Array(.LeftHeader, .CenterHeader, .RightHeader, .LeftFooter, .CenterFooter, .RightFooter)
         If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(0), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
            .LeftHeader = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), HeaderSave(Index)(0))
            HeaderChanged(Index, 0) = True
         End If
         If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(1), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
            .CenterHeader = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), HeaderSave(Index)(1))
            HeaderChanged(Index, 1) = True
         End If
         If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(2), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
            .RightHeader = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), HeaderSave(Index)(2))
            HeaderChanged(Index, 2) = True
         End If
         If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(3), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
            .LeftFooter = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), HeaderSave(Index)(3))
            HeaderChanged(Index, 3) = True
         End If
         If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(4), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
            .CenterFooter = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), HeaderSave(Index)(4))
            HeaderChanged(Index, 4) = True
         End If
         If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(5), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
            .RightFooter = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), HeaderSave(Index)(5))
            HeaderChanged(Index, 5) = True
         End If
      End With
   Next Index
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

' Next line added by sbv 2024-09-12 to bring up the print dialog automatically after header has been updated
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show
    ' ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut

' Next two lines commented out to run the Restore macro without having to do so manually
'    End Sub
'    Public Sub RestoreHeaders()
'
' Now restore the header back to the variable [Cell:A1]
   Dim IndexB As Long
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   For IndexB = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
      With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(IndexB).PageSetup
         If HeaderChanged(IndexB, 0) Then .LeftHeader = HeaderSave(IndexB)(0)
         If HeaderChanged(IndexB, 1) Then .CenterHeader = HeaderSave(IndexB)(1)
         If HeaderChanged(IndexB, 2) Then .RightHeader = HeaderSave(IndexB)(2)
         If HeaderChanged(IndexB, 3) Then .LeftFooter = HeaderSave(IndexB)(3)
         If HeaderChanged(IndexB, 4) Then .CenterFooter = HeaderSave(IndexB)(4)
         If HeaderChanged(IndexB, 5) Then .RightFooter = HeaderSave(IndexB)(5)
      End With
   Next IndexB
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Function SubstituteCellValues( _
      ByVal FocusSheet As Worksheet, _
      ByVal Text As String _
   ) As String

' Look for the text "^[Cell:A1]" and replace it with the cell's value. The cell
' reference can be any valid cell reference with or without a sheet name. If no
' sheet name is included the sheet for which the header or footer text is
' defined is assumed.
  
   Dim StartPos As Long
   Dim EndPos As Long
   Dim FindText As String
   Dim ReplaceText As String
   Dim CellReference As String
  
   Do
      StartPos = InStr(Text, "^[Cell:")
      If StartPos > 0 Then
         EndPos = InStr(StartPos, Text, "]")
         If EndPos = 0 Then Exit Do
         FindText = Mid(Text, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos + 1)
         CellReference = Mid(FindText, 8, Len(FindText) - 8)
         If InStr(CellReference, "!") = 0 Then
            CellReference = "'" & FocusSheet.Name & "'!" & CellReference
         End If
         On Error Resume Next
         ReplaceText = Range(CellReference).Value
         On Error GoTo 0
         Text = Replace(Text, FindText, ReplaceText)
      Else
         Exit Do
      End If
   Loop

   SubstituteCellValues = Text

End Function

Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
   SaveAndSetHeaders
   Application.OnTime Now, "ThisWorkbook.Workbook_AfterPrint"
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_AfterPrint()
   RestoreHeaders
End Sub

' Notes
'
' The code in this article was developed with the following knowledge of Excel behavior:
'
' There is no "after" print event generated, only a "before" print event. Also, when the Workbook_BeforePrint even handler
' is called by Excel, it is impossible to tell what objects are about to be printed. This makes it impossible to emulate
' the printing task within the BeforePrint routine. If it were possible, then the header and footer setup code and restore
' code could both reside in the BeforePrint routine. Because of these two limitations, a custom "AfterPrint" routine is required.
'
' When an Application.OnTime request is made from within the BeforePrint routine, the routine to be called is not invoked until
' all requested printing activity has been completed. This behavior allows the OnTime request to execute the custom "AfterPrint"
' routine without that execution overlapping the printing process.
'
' When invoked as part of a VBA request to print, any attempts to change the headers and footers from within the BeforePrint
' event handler or any subordinate routine are ignored. Hence the need to specifically call the header and footer setup and restore
' routines when printing from VBA.
'
' Another idea is to move the Eastern rows to a second worksheet and then set the headers of each sheet accordingly.
'
' Kevin


After setting the DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter to True you need to assign values to the header/footer sections for the first page.
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index).PageSetup
    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
    .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = "Page First"
    .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
    .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
End With


I tried this, neether one worked:

I tried
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index).PageSetup
' With Worksheets(1).PageSetup  - commenting made no diff
.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True
' End With  - commenting made no diff
HeaderSave(Index) = Array(.LeftHeader, .CenterHeader, .RightHeader, .LeftFooter, .CenterFooter, .RightFooter)
If InStr(HeaderSave(Index)(1), "^[Cell:") > 0 Then
.FirstPageCenterHeader.Text = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), HeaderSave(Index)(1))
.CenterHeader = SubstituteCellValues(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Index), HeaderSave(Index)(1))
HeaderChanged(Index, 1) = True
End If

I'm focusing on the center header only. I can't format code properly in a comment. how is that done?

Have you tried a break point where the call to SubstituteCellValues is called to check on the return value?
